# Selecting an element depending on attribute's value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui, element

How can I select an element on the form and perform click action on it using jQuery? Here's an example for what I want:

If I have many image buttons created on the runtime and here's one of them:

```html
<img class="arrow arrowDown" onclick="toggleMyChildren(this);" alt="" src="/sp.gif" complete="complete" svalue="2"/>
```

How can I select this element and perform "Click" action on it depending on the value of attribute's (`svalue`) value?

Comment: Have you tried the "attribute equals" selector? If you're going to use jQuery, why not spend ten minutes browsing through the online doco's [list of selectors](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("img[svalue=2]").on("click", function() {

    var attr = $(this).attr("svalue")
    alert(attr);

  });
});
```

or if you need attribute on click :

```
function toggleMyChildren(ooo) {
  var attr = $(ooo).attr("svalue")
  alert(attr);
}
```

Comment: i used  $("img[svalue=2]").click(); , but could you explain (is "img" referring to input name ?)

Comment: No. `<img src="" alt="" />`  referring to tag name.